# c# pointer to function member without an instance of object

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to develop event model in c#. I'm a newbie to c# by have an experience in c++. My question is: can I create a delegate to a method without having an instance of the class. Look a this code:

```
public delegate void _CurrentDelegate<EventData>( EventData ev );


public class EventInterface{

    public void Call<EventData>( _CurrentDelegate<EventData> methodToInvoke, EventData data ){
        methodToInvoke( data );
    }
}

public class EventClass {

    protected List<EventInterface> _Listeners;

    private bool _InBlock;

    public EventClass(){
        _Listeners = new List<EventInterface>();
        _InBlock = false;
    }

    public void AddListener( EventInterface listener ){

        if ( _Listeners.Find( predicate => predicate.Equals(listener) ) != null )
            return;

        _Listeners.Add( listener );

    }

    public void RemoveListener( EventInterface listener ){
        if ( _Listeners.Find( predicate => predicate.Equals(listener) ) != null )
            _Listeners.Remove( listener );
    }

    public void BlockEvents( bool Block ){
        _InBlock = Block;
    }


    public void Signal<EventData>( _CurrentDelegate<EventData> methodToInvoke, EventData data ){
        if ( !_InBlock ){
            foreach( EventInterface listener in _Listeners ){
                listener.Call( methodToInvoke, data );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So, I'm trying to create a template event class where I can store my Listeners. In method Signal I'm trying to pass a delegate to a method, which every listener must execute.

Expample should look. like this:

```
public class TableManagerEvents : EventInterface {

    virtual public void OnMatchDetected( List<int> matches ) {}
}

public class TableManager : AstronomatchData.EventClass {
     public void CheckTable(){
        List<int> matches = new List<int>();
        TableManagerEvents newev = new TableManagerEvents();

        AddListener( newev );

        _CurrentDelegate<List<int>> del = TableManagerEvents.OnMatchDetected; // problem
        Signal( del, matches ); 
    }

}
```

A that line, which is marked as problem, I get an error error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member.

The one solution I found is to make a `TableManagerEvents.OnMatchDetected` static, but that is not what I want.

I'm trying to find a solution for 3 days, but there's no.

Comment: There's already an event model in .Net, which is basically an array of delegates under the hood. What is missing in the OOB events to fulfill your requirement?

Comment: As defined, `OnMatchDetected` is an instance method. That is not even close to a static delegate field/property, which appears to be what you need.

Comment: You should have a look at an intro to C# tutorial/book. You are coding as if C# and C++ were the same language (e.g. your `EventInterface` should just be an `interface`, rather than the C++ "class with only pure virtual methods".) As well, as Steve B points out, C# already has a built-in and robust eventing system.

Comment: Besides you might want to make `_CurrentDelegate` generic, like `_CurrentDelegate<T>( T ev )` so this code works: `_CurrentDelegate<List<int>>`. You can use the `Action` or `Function` generic delegates. On the `mscorlib` assembly, `System` namespace (`public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);`

Comment: @dlev i'm trying to learn c# :)

Comment: @polkduran it is a template

Comment: @VladSviatetskyi Which I think is awesome :) I'm just saying that an online tutorial that covers some of the basics would help a lot here (especially with the `event` stuff, which is powerful, but tricky.)

Comment: @dlev, we can say so, C# generics are like C++ templates

Comment: @VladSviatetskyi take a look at this tutorial about `event`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @polkduran I'm not sure why you are targeting those comments at me. Perhaps they were meant for Vlad?

Comment: @dlev, yes sorry :P, I just could edit one

Comment: @polkduran yeah, I already know that :)

Comment: @VladSviatetskyi, we can say so, C# generics are like C++ templates (double comment because I targeted it to the wrong person)

Comment: @polkduran: C++ templates and C# generics overlap in that they're both good for making type-safe collections.  But they're very different in many regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "open delegate" with one of the `Delegate.Create` overloads -- the target object becomes a parameter of the delegate (you won't need your `Call` helper function, just `methodToInvoke(listener, data)`.

However, as Uatec said, in versions of C# that support lambdas, they are much easier to use than open delegates.  (Mostly because the C# language doesn't support open delegates directly, but forces you to use reflection to create them.)

You also have a type-safety issue, because all your listeners are `EventInterface`, but not all objects implementing `EventInterface` have an `OnMatchDetected` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Lambda expressions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) to represent your callback instead of delegate objects. You can create them anywhere like variables, pass them around like function pointers, and execute them like methods/functions. They are also a type of delegate, so compatible with all that too.

Comment: A lambda expression is just a method without a name. In order to store subscribers/listeners you still need a delegate to hold a reference to them.

Comment: Dirk, a collection of Funcs or Actions could store them.

Comment: Func or Action are delegates.

Comment: Yes. However I think that the usage patterns provided by Func/Action are much easier to handle than delegates and maintaining instances of event handlers.

Comment: @Uatec, `Action<T>` => `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to invoke the function on the `newev` object, right?  Then you need something more like:

```
_CurrentDelegate<List<int>> del = newev.OnMatchDetected;
```

I'll echo the comments that say that you're reinventing .Net events/delegates here.  They do seem confusing at first, but then they'll click and you'll just get it.  It's worth the time trying to solve your problem without writing your own event routing code.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to not register listeners in the event classes but instead have some kind of router?

Example:

```
public class Event
{

}

public abstract class EventHandler
{
    public abstract void Handle(Event e);
}

public class EventHandler<T> : EventHandler where T : Event
{
    private readonly Action<T> _action;

    public EventHandler(Action<T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public override void Handle(Event e)
    {
        _action((T) e);
    }
}

public static class EventRouter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, List<EventHandler>> Handlers = new Dictionary<Type, List<EventHandler>>();

    public static void Register<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : Event
    {
        List<EventHandler> list = null;

        if(Handlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
        {
            list.Add(new EventHandler<T>(handler));
            return;
        }

        Handlers[typeof(T)] = new List<EventHandler>() { new EventHandler<T>(handler)};
    }

    public static void Signal(Event e)
    {
        List<EventHandler> list = null;

        if(Handlers.TryGetValue(e.GetType(), out list))
        {
            list.ForEach(h => h.Handle(e));
        }
    }

    public static void Signal<T>(Action<T> init) where T : Event, new()
    {
        var e = new T();
        init(e);

        Signal(e);
    }
}
```